# Compare two array-values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I managed to write information from a database into an array. This information is divided into two different arrays.
But these arrays have to be put together now.

For example:
On 2020-09-08 I had in the first array in the area 'reason-codes' **Reason1** with the 'count' of **1**

In the second array I also had on 2020-09-08 in the area 'reason-codes' **Reason1** with the count **3**.

Now I have to add the counts in array1 or array2, if there are the same reason codes in array1 and array2.

I ask myself how I can do this, because the Reasons can always appear in a different place. I tried it with two foreach loops - but this did not work very well.

How could I do this?

Array 1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 2020-09-08
            [shift] => Production
            [total_units] => 3000
            [reason-codes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason1
                            [duration] => 24
                            [count] => 2
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason2
                            [duration] => 37
                            [count] => 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason3
                            [duration] => 3
                            [count] => 1
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason5
                            [duration] => 14
                            [count] => 1
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason6
                            [duration] => 2
                            [count] => 1
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason7
                            [duration] => 65
                            [count] => 5
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 2020-09-09
            [shift] => Production
            [total_units] => 4000
            [reason-codes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason1
                            [duration] => 61
                            [count] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason2
                            [duration] => 35
                            [count] => 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason3
                            [duration] => 9
                            [count] => 1
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason 4
                            [duration] => 214
                            [count] => 9
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Array 2:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 2020-09-08
            [shift] => Production
            [reason-codes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason3
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 34
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason2
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 16
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason4
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 2
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason1
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 3
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason5
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 1
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason6
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 3
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason7
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 1
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason8
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 2
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason9
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 1
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason10
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 2
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason12
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 1
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason11
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 9
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason14
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 4
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason20
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 1
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason17
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [timestamp] => 2020-09-09
            [shift] => Production
            [reason-codes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason4
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 4
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason2
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 7
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason3
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 4
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason10
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 1
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason11
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 4
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason14
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 1
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason20
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 1
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason15
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 1
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason12
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 4
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [reason] => Reason22
                            [duration] => 1
                            [count] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: is 'timestamp' is a unique field for each array list?

Comment: Hi, yes timestamp is unique. Array1 and Array2 have got everytime the same timestamp

Comment: What have you tried ?